# RegExp for .exec() and .split() are not working the same

Tags: javascript, regex

I tried to split flight connections to separate airports with `.split(' - ')`, but there is one airport that have this character in it's name. Because of that I'm now forced to use regular expression. I'm not sure why, but when I perform `reg.exec(a)` it finds only one character (correctly!), but when I do `.split(reg)` it splits in three parts instead of two.

Anyone know why is that happening and what can I do with it so I can use this pattern for `split`?

Code:

```
const a = "Cristoforo Colombo Airport, Genoa, Italy (GOA) - Augsburg - Muehlhausen Airport, Munich, Germany (AGB)"
const b = "Augsburg - Muehlhausen Airport, Munich, Germany (AGB) - Strachowice Airport, Wroclaw, Poland (WRO)"

const reg = /(?<=,.*,.*) - /

console.log(reg.exec(a))

console.log(a.split(reg))
console.log(b.split(reg))
```

Link to code example: https://repl.it/repls/AltruisticUnitedSmalltalk

Link to RegEx101: https://regex101.com/r/8HOSpz/4

Comment: If you give -1 at least comment why

Comment: The regex for `split` specifies on what to divide the string. That is, it specifies a pattern that will *not* be included in the array that is returned, but strings to the left and right of that pattern will be. When you do an `exec`, you need to specify the pattern that *you want returned*, that is, the *opposite* of the pattern used for `split` (more or less, anyway).

Comment: @Booboo i believe op was wondering why only one hyphen was returned with exec, but split returned three parts

Comment: Yes, the thing about implicit global flag within `split` makes sense. I just thought it will use the whole pattern to split - which was in my mind "split on dash, but only if preceded by two commas with chars between them", but turned out to be "split on every dash after two commas are found".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The pattern

Your split pattern has a variable length look-behind assertion, which causes overlaps:

```
Cristoforo Colombo Airport, Genoa, Italy (GOA) - Augsburg -
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Satisfies the assertion
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Also satisfies the assertion
```

#### About `exec`

You only saw one match being returned with `exec`, because the `/g` (global) flag wasn't specified; with the global flag enabled, calling it once will return the first match, but it returns another result if you call it again:

```js
const a = "Cristoforo Colombo Airport, Genoa, Italy (GOA) - Augsburg - Muehlhausen Airport, Munich, Germany (AGB)"
const reg = /(?<=,.*,.*) - /g
let match

while ((match = reg.exec(a)) !== null) {
  console.log(`Found ${match[0]}. Next starts at ${reg.lastIndex}.`);
}
```

#### About `split`

When `split()` is called with a regular expression, it's implicitly copied as an expression *with* global flag enabled; it then iterates over those matches, as seen in the above snippet, and creates an array of string slices based on those results.

#### Alternative

From what I can tell, the airports all have a call sign between parentheses at the end of their name; therefore, your look-behind assertion can be fixed like this:

```js
const a = "Cristoforo Colombo Airport, Genoa, Italy (GOA) - Augsburg - Muehlhausen Airport, Munich, Germany (AGB)"
const b = "Augsburg - Muehlhausen Airport, Munich, Germany (AGB) - Strachowice Airport, Wroclaw, Poland (WRO)"

const reg = /(?<=\)) - /

console.log(a.split(reg))
console.log(b.split(reg))
```

Comment: Nice one! I haven't thought about it that way - so that solves the problem of *how* to do this. Still, I would love to understand *why* `split` is not working the same as `exec`. Or in other words - why my original pattern don't work with `split()`?

Comment: @jeand'arme added a full explanation as to why exec and split seemingly work differently.

Comment: Thank you! This is very explanatory - so `split` has implicit global flag. Makes sense a bit given it's function.